# ionic/angular ng-click calls wrong function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

The following code works fine if you log in and logout, but if you try to login after that the ng-click="login()"  calls the logout() function. The DOM is update correctly.

```
.controller('AppCtrl', function($scope) {
function updateMenu(){
    $scope.customMenuItems = [];
    if(loggedin){
        $scope.customMenuItems.push({'text':'Login','click':'login()'});
    }else{
        $scope.customMenuItems.push({'text':'Logout','click':'logout()'});
    }
}
updateMenu();

$scope.login(){
loggedin= true; 
updateMenu();
}

$scope.logout(){
loggedin= false;
updateMenu();
}
```

and menu.html

```
 <ion-list>
     <ion-item menu-close ng-click="{{item.click}}" ng-repeat="item in customMenuItems track by $index">
         {{item.text}}
     </ion-item>
 </ion-list>
```

Comment: Hmm... I'm not sure passing a function name as a string is a good approach. Why not handle that logic in your controller? Also, double braces aren't needed inside `ngClick`.

Comment: it doesn't work without double braces. item.click wont substituted.

Comment: Why not add the right function directly, `{'text':'Login','click': $scope.login}`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not think it is a good idea to pass the handler as string on the bound data. Also if you see the console you will see parser error because `ng-click` needs an expression and presence of interpolation will make it an invalid expression. For the answer sake you could use [`$eval`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$eval) function of the `scope` (it is not same as javascript eval) that can evaluate valid angular expression against the scope, i.e something like:

```
 ng-click="$eval(item.click)"

<ion-item menu-close ng-click="$eval(item.click)" ng-repeat="item in customMenuItems track by $index">
     {{item.text}}
 </ion-item>
```

Also there are some logic issues in the code as well.

**Demo**

```js
angular.module('app', []).controller('AppCtrl', function($scope) {
  var loggedin = false;

  function updateMenu() {
    $scope.customMenuItems = [];
    if (!loggedin) {
      $scope.customMenuItems.push({
        'text': 'Login',
        'click': 'login()'
      });
    } else {
      $scope.customMenuItems.push({
        'text': 'Logout',
        'click': 'logout()'
      });
    }
  }

  updateMenu();

  $scope.login = function() {
    loggedin = true;
    console.log("login");
    updateMenu();
  }

  $scope.logout = function() {
    loggedin = false;
    console.log("logout");
    updateMenu();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.0/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="AppCtrl">

  <div menu-close ng-click="$eval(item.click)" ng-repeat="item in customMenuItems track by $index">
    {{item.text}}
  </div>
</div>
```

But ideally i would prefer doing it more *explicitly* than doing some *black magic* :), i.e as a simple approach render specific button with click handler based on the logic instead of handling the method calls via magic string in the data being bound or passing function references around.

Answer (score 0):

A couple other possibilities:

(1) For some reason method names (perhaps due to a convention-over-configuration artifact) can interfere with which method gets fired. Also:

(2) If you mix absolute and relative positioning you can have an element with transparency that overlaps something below (or beside) it. It can completely overlap it while still showing it if it is transparent.